# King of Captures

Tags: optimization, checkerboard

[image]

The player's black King (above) is about to capture the remaining opponent pieces as continuation of his move and 10 white pieces have already been captured on the same turn/move. **What is the position before the move? How can the king captured all 12 pieces on a single move?**

Checkers Rules:
King captures by jumping over a single opponent piece. The diagonal jump from current position to any unoccupied square (ranges 2 to 7 squares) must continue as long as there are another possible captures. Succeeding captures can be forward or 90 deg. turn  prior to last jump direction.

Comment: "How can the king capture all 12 pieces on a single move?" There are only 2 white checkers left, and it appears he just became a king going from 27 -> 20.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how he is "About to capture the remaining pieces." given his current position. Is this to say: "The king captured 10 pieces on the last turn, how could he have captured all 12?"

Comment: The rules is somewhat a brazillian checkers/draughts.

Comment: @leigero-the captures of the last 2 white pieces ..from square 20 to 2 then to 13 are part of his on-going move/turn of 12 pieces capture.

Comment: Alright, so even if you've captured pieces on the same turn, you can still use them as part of another jump? (That is, capturing isn't "final" until your jump sequence is over, and you've removed the non-final captures?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I understand the rules correctly: the king can jump over and remove any single piece, but the jump can be any distance. Given this understanding, here is a solution:

White pieces are at 7,8, (9), (11), 14, 15, 16, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27 (the bracketed pieces are the ones shown on the OP's board).

Black's king is at 32 (having moved there from 28 perhaps).

> Then black's moves are as follows (where bracket refers to the white piece being taken):
>  32-(27)-23
>  23-(26)-30
>  30-(25)-21
>  21-(14)-10
>  10-(15)-19
>  19-(16)-12
>  12-(8)-3
>  3-(7)-17
>  17-(22)-31
>  31-(24)-20 (which is the starting position)
>  20-(11)-2
>  2-(9)-13

Here's an animation:

> [image]